# Vue show next 10 items when press button

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to do load more function.  When load more button is clicked show next 10 hidden items in v-for `allCategories` loop.

```
<template v-for="(category, i) in allCategories">
            <v-col :key="i" v-show="i <= 10" class="col-6 col-sm-4">
              <v-checkbox
              dense
              color="black"
              :label="category.title"
              :value="isCategoryChecked(category.id)"
              @click="() => selectCategory(category.id)"
            />
            </v-col>
          </template>
```

load more button

```
<v-btn color="black white--text"
   @click="showMoreCategories"
    :loading="loading">
    {{ $t('general.loadMore') }}
</v-btn>
```

showMoreCategories function

```
showMoreCategories() {

  }
```

How do i implement this?

Comment: make `10` dynamic, btw you should limit the allCategories not just hide the others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your variable `allCategories` contains all the categories you could possibly want (i.e. you don't have to fetch additional categories from a server or local store) then you can replace `v-show="i <= 10"` with `v-show="i <= numberOfCategoriesToShow"`. Where `numberOfCategoriesToShow` is a new variable you have defined and initially set to 10.

Then your `showMoreCategories` function would look like this

```
showMoreCategories() {
   this.numberOfCategoriesToShow += 10;
}
```